# Chaining pattern rules in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that, if simplified, boils down to this:

```
.PHONY: FORCE
FORCE:

a-%-b: FORCE
        @echo 'a-$*-b'

c-%-d: a-%-b
```

If I run `make a-test-b`, it prints `a-test-b`, as expected. However, if I try `make c-test-d`, it fails with

```
make: *** No rule to make target `c-test-d'.  Stop.
```

Is there any way I can make this work? This seems confusing to me, since something like this works:

```
%.txt1:
        touch $*.txt1

%.txt2: %.txt1
        cp $< $@
```

Here, I also have a pattern rule that has the target of another pattern rule as a prerequisite; however, contrary to the example above, it works perfectly well if I do `make test.txt2` - it happily creates test.txt1 first, then copies it as test.txt2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because this:

```
c-%-d: a-%-b
```

does not define a pattern rule.  It [cancels a pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) (which doesn't exist anyway).  If you want to create a pattern rule you have to provide a recipe that the rule will run, even just this is sufficient:

```
c-%-d: a-%-b ;
```

(adding the `;`).